# Problems with Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband card

Tags: networking, modem, 3g

I've got a new Dell Latitude e7440, and a Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ mobile broadband card. I cannot get the broadband card to work.

I can see the card:

```
# lshw
  ....
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: 46:51:4c:75:9d:ad
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

And I can get rid of the DISABLED text:

```
# ifconfig wwan0 up
# ifconfig wwan0
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:51:4c:75:9d:ad  
          inet6 addr: fe80::4451:4cff:fe75:9dad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3937 (3.9 KB)
# lshw
  ....
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: 46:51:4c:75:9d:ad
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=yes multicast=yes
```

But I cannot *use* the card in any way.

- There's no `/dev/ttyUSBx` to which I could input AT commands.
- I cannot see a mobile broadband connection in the Network manager.
- tools like `mbim-network` simply say the connection to the modem failed

My Dell BIOS version is `A10`, and from BIOS I can see the card. It's enabled and from that perspective there shouldn't be anything wrong with it. If I need to debug the driver, I'm willing to give that a try but I need some pointers on where to start. Any help is much appreciated.

Below is a list of debug output. Please ask for more in the comments if you think of anything that's helpful.

---

Here's `lsusb -v`:

```
# lsusb -v
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 413c:81a3 Dell Computer Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x413c Dell Computer Corp.
  idProduct          0x81a3 
  bcdDevice            0.06
  iManufacturer           1 Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
  iProduct                2 Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ (42Mbps) Mobile Broadband Card
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      2
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          204
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 00
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000c  1x 12 bytes
        bInterval               9
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 00
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000c  1x 12 bytes
        bInterval               9
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        8
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               9
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        ** UNRECOGNIZED:  2c ff 42 49 53 54 00 01 07 f5 40 f6 00 00 00 00 01 f7 c4 09 02 f8 c4 09 03 f9 88 13 04 fa 10 27 05 fb 10 27 06 fc c4 09 07 fd c4 09
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           82
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     2
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface        12
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass      14 
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber       12
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass     14 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC MBIM:
        bcdMBIMVersion       1.00
        wMaxControlMessage   4096
        bNumberFilters       16
        bMaxFilterSize       128
        wMaxSegmentSize      4064
        bmNetworkCapabilities 0x20
          8-byte ntb input size
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber       13
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber       13
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      2
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

And the `usb-devices` output for the modem:

```
# usb-devices
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=02 Dev#= 17 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=81a3 Rev=00.06
S:  Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S:  Product=Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ (42Mbps) Mobile Broadband Card
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 2 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: c: invalid number
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=0e Prot=00 Driver=cdc_mbim
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: d: invalid number
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=02 Driver=cdc_mbim
```

Here's the `rfkill`-information:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dell_laptop/rfkill
status: 0x1015D
Bit 0 : Hardware switch supported:   1
Bit 1 : Wifi locator supported:      0
Bit 2 : Wifi is supported:           1
Bit 3 : Bluetooth is supported:      1
Bit 4 : WWAN is supported:           1
Bit 5 : Wireless keyboard supported: 0
Bit 8 : Wifi is installed:           1
Bit 9 : Bluetooth is installed:      0
Bit 10: WWAN is installed:           0
Bit 16: Hardware switch is on:       1
Bit 17: Wifi is blocked:             0
Bit 18: Bluetooth is blocked:        0
Bit 19: WWAN is blocked:             0

hwswitch_state: 0x1F
Bit 0 : Wifi controlled by switch:      1
Bit 1 : Bluetooth controlled by switch: 1
Bit 2 : WWAN controlled by switch:      1
Bit 7 : Wireless switch config locked:  0
Bit 8 : Wifi locator enabled:           0
Bit 15: Wifi locator setting locked:    0
```

This is what you can see via `dmesg` whenever the device is enabled:

```
[ 2101.897753] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 2102.026467] usb 2-7: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 8 but max is 3
[ 2102.026480] usb 2-7: config 1 has no interface number 1
[ 2102.026926] usb 2-7: config 2 has an invalid interface number: 12 but max is 1
[ 2102.026930] usb 2-7: config 2 has an invalid interface number: 13 but max is 1
[ 2102.026941] usb 2-7: config 2 has an invalid interface number: 13 but max is 1
[ 2102.026942] usb 2-7: config 2 has no interface number 0
[ 2102.026943] usb 2-7: config 2 has no interface number 1
[ 2102.027618] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=81a3
[ 2102.027621] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2102.027623] usb 2-7: Product: Dell Wireless 5570 HSPA+ (42Mbps) Mobile Broadband Card
[ 2102.027624] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
[ 2102.029821] cdc_mbim 2-7:2.12: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[ 2102.029954] cdc_mbim 2-7:2.12 wwan0: register 'cdc_mbim' at usb-0000:00:14.0-7, CDC MBIM, 46:51:4c:75:9d:ad
```

`nmcli` output:

```
# nmcli nm status
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

This is what I get when I try to start it with `mbim-network`:

```
# mbim-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
Querying subscriber ready status 'mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --query-subscriber-ready-status --no-close'...
error: couldn't open the MbimDevice: Failure

Querying registration state 'mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --query-registration-state --no-open= --no-close'...
error: invalid transaction ID specified: 

Attaching to packet service with 'mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --attach-packet-service --no-open= --no-close'...
error: invalid transaction ID specified: 
Starting network with 'mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --connect= --no-open= --no-close'...
error: invalid transaction ID specified: 
Network start failed
```

The driver should be OK, grepping for the vendor and product id combination from `modprobe` output:

```
# modprobe -c | grep -i 413c.*81a3
alias usb:v413Cp81A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in00* qcserial
alias usb:v413Cp81A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in02* qcserial
alias usb:v413Cp81A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in03* qcserial
alias usb:v413Cp81A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in08* qmi_wwan
```

Here's my Linux version. I'm running a modified kernel due to a multiheading docking station problem, but this modem issue occurs identically on the 3.13 kernel which was the default when I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

```
# uname -a
Linux slartibartfast 3.15.0-rc8+ #5 SMP Mon Jul 21 14:18:58 EEST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using `libqmi` and `qmicli`, I get some interaction with the modem, but still some fairly confusing error messages. I have not yet had time to look into this further.

```
$ sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --verbose --wds-start-network= --client-no-release-cid
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] QMI Device at '/dev/cdc-wdm0' ready
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Assuming service 'wds' is supported...
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Allocating new client ID...
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message...
<<<<<< RAW:
<<<<<<   length = 16
<<<<<<   data   = 01:0F:00:00:00:00:00:01:22:00:04:00:01:01:00:01

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message (translated)...
<<<<<< QMUX:
<<<<<<   length  = 15
<<<<<<   flags   = 0x00
<<<<<<   service = "ctl"
<<<<<<   client  = 0
<<<<<< QMI:
<<<<<<   flags       = "none"
<<<<<<   transaction = 1
<<<<<<   tlv_length  = 4
<<<<<<   message     = "Allocate CID" (0x0022)
<<<<<< TLV:
<<<<<<   type       = "Service" (0x01)
<<<<<<   length     = 1
<<<<<<   value      = 01
<<<<<<   translated = wds

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message...
>>>>>> RAW:
>>>>>>   length = 24
>>>>>>   data   = 01:17:00:80:00:00:01:01:22:00:0C:00:02:04:00:00:00:00:00:01:02:00:01:08

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message (translated)...
>>>>>> QMUX:
>>>>>>   length  = 23
>>>>>>   flags   = 0x80
>>>>>>   service = "ctl"
>>>>>>   client  = 0
>>>>>> QMI:
>>>>>>   flags       = "response"
>>>>>>   transaction = 1
>>>>>>   tlv_length  = 12
>>>>>>   message     = "Allocate CID" (0x0022)
>>>>>> TLV:
>>>>>>   type       = "Result" (0x02)
>>>>>>   length     = 4
>>>>>>   value      = 00:00:00:00
>>>>>>   translated = SUCCESS
>>>>>> TLV:
>>>>>>   type       = "Allocation Info" (0x01)
>>>>>>   length     = 2
>>>>>>   value      = 01:08
>>>>>>   translated = [ service = 'wds' cid = '8' ]

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Registered 'wds' (version unknown) client with ID '8'
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] Asynchronously starting network...
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message...
<<<<<< RAW:
<<<<<<   length = 13
<<<<<<   data   = 01:0C:00:00:01:08:00:01:00:20:00:00:00

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Sent message (translated)...
<<<<<< QMUX:
<<<<<<   length  = 12
<<<<<<   flags   = 0x00
<<<<<<   service = "wds"
<<<<<<   client  = 8
<<<<<< QMI:
<<<<<<   flags       = "none"
<<<<<<   transaction = 1
<<<<<<   tlv_length  = 0
<<<<<<   message     = "Start Network" (0x0020)

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message...
>>>>>> RAW:
>>>>>>   length = 32
>>>>>>   data   = 01:1F:00:80:01:08:02:01:00:20:00:13:00:02:04:00:01:00:0E:00:10:02:00:03:00:11:04:00:03:00:D1:07

[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Received message (translated)...
>>>>>> QMUX:
>>>>>>   length  = 31
>>>>>>   flags   = 0x80
>>>>>>   service = "wds"
>>>>>>   client  = 8
>>>>>> QMI:
>>>>>>   flags       = "response"
>>>>>>   transaction = 1
>>>>>>   tlv_length  = 19
>>>>>>   message     = "Start Network" (0x0020)
>>>>>> TLV:
>>>>>>   type       = "Result" (0x02)
>>>>>>   length     = 4
>>>>>>   value      = 01:00:0E:00
>>>>>>   translated = FAILURE: CallFailed
>>>>>> TLV:
>>>>>>   type       = "Call End Reason" (0x10)
>>>>>>   length     = 2
>>>>>>   value      = 03:00
>>>>>>   translated = generic-no-service
>>>>>> TLV:
>>>>>>   type       = "Verbose Call End Reason" (0x11)
>>>>>>   length     = 4
>>>>>>   value      = 03:00:D1:07
>>>>>>   translated = [ type = 'cm' reason = '2001' ]

error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed'
call end reason (3): generic-no-service
verbose call end reason (3,2001): [cm] no-service
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Client ID not released:
    Service: 'wds'
        CID: '8'
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Unregistered 'wds' client with ID '8'
[27 elo 2014, 12:41:16] [Debug] Client released
```

I can also set my PIN code with `qmcli`:

```
# qmicli --dms-uim-verify-pin=PIN,xxxx -d /dev/cdc-wdm0
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] PIN verified successfully
```

And get some information:

```
# qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-get-manufacturer 
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Device manufacturer retrieved:
    Manufacturer: 'Sierra Wireless, Incorporated'

# qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-get-model
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Device model retrieved:
    Model: 'MC8805'

# qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-get-capabilities
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Device capabilities retrieved:
    Max TX channel rate: '5742000'
    Max RX channel rate: '42200000'
           Data Service: 'non-simultaneous-cs-ps'
                    SIM: 'supported'
               Networks: 'gsm, umts'
```

Regarding @aleksander's question in the comments of his answer, here's the error when using the apn:

```
error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed'
call end reason (3): generic-no-service
verbose call end reason (3,2001): [cm] no-service
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Client ID not released:
    Service: 'wds'
        CID: '1'
[19 marras 2014, 13:30:30] [Debug] [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Unregistered 'wds' client with ID '1'
[19 marras 2014, 13:30:30] [Debug] Client released
```

Comment: See [my answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159086/difference-between-ppp0-vs-wwan0/159091#159091) to understand what's happening here. As Aleksander states below, you're missing half the interface.   If your using an ISP, you need to authenticate with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell branded Sierra Wireless modems, like the 5570 (bought one myself now) need a magic "DMS Set FCC Auth" command to recover from low-power mode, better explained here: https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/dell-branded-sierra-wireless-3g4g-modem-not-online/

If you're using ModemManager, you can try to compile your one `libqmi` and ModemManager from git to get this fixed.

Comment: Just released libqmi 1.12.4 and ModemManager 1.4.4 with these fixes; time to poke your distro to get them integrated :)

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking the APN in the `--wds-start-network` option. You wouldn't need it if you were in a CDMA/EVDO network, but it is (usually) required an explicit one in GSM/UMTS/LTE.

Once QMI WDS Start Network returns with no error, just try to run `dhclient` in the WWAN interface.

Comment: I've tried it with my providers apn, which is `internet`. Produces the same error. The card works fine in my phone with both no APN and the APN I just mentioned above. I'll give it a new try and post some more comments.

Comment: Yeah confirming that I'm getting the same error as before, even after first setting my pin code and then attempting to start the network.

Comment: Is it really the "generic-no-service" call end reason, even when you use the APN?

Comment: I've edited the exact error message to the question now, at the end. It is the generic-no-service.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using a SIM card with PIN lock disabled or did you already send the PIN?

Comment: Pin lock is not disabled, but I've sent the PIN it with `qmicli`.

Comment: The kernel driver is not there yet https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78851

Comment: That kernel bugreport is actually showing the same issue I'm talking about in my other reply. Should be now handled correctly by libqmi git master.